# Summary function not sorting .csv data entirely

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have a .csv that has data that looks like so:
First name Last initial,1/0,1/0,....

It is either a 1 or 0 depending on the persons choice from a txt file that contains 50 pairs of choices.
E.g. Apple
Pear
Dog
Cat

My issue is that my method (classSummary) that keeps count of how many people select the choices only goes halfway and the count is incorrect.

Here is my code as it stands, and any advice would be much appreciated:

```
   public static void classSummary() {
    for (Student student : data) {
        int[] answers = student.getAnswers();
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if (answers[i] == 0) {
                choices.get(i).setCount(choices.get(i).getCount() + 1);
            }
```

Comment: How are the two `Choices.txt` and `Students.csv` files related to each other? Does they have the same row count? What means __"choices only goes halfway and the count is incorrect"__ Only haif of the file content is included? Only first half of result is correct? Can you share a sample data of your files containing 3 or 4 lines each and the expected output?

Comment: @Eritrean I updated the post like you said.

Comment: This code doesn’t group the choices into pairs, so when you call  `choices.get(i)`, that retrieves the wrong option for any value of `i` greater than `0`.

Comment: It also doesn’t count anything when the answer is `1`.

Comment: You have 99 items in choises.txt but each student has only a record of 49 ints representing the choices. Why do you expect to get a value for all available choices?

Comment: Hint: you can calculate the correct position in the `choices` array given the value of `i` and the value of `answers[i]`. Try doing it in paper first until you see the pattern, then convert that to code.

Comment: I am assuming `Danny F,1,0,0,1,`  is interpreted as that the student has choosen only `PC` and `Winter` from `PC Coke Pepsi Winter` if we take the first 4 inputs into account. Is that correct?

Comment: @Eritrean My bad, I misplaced MAC, so it should be 100 choices now. Also, yes it would be binary choices so Danny chose PC, Coke, Winter, and batman.

Comment: Okay, so 0 = choosen and 1 = not chosen? But still, with the input `Danny F,1,0,0,1,0,0,1` and `Mac PC Coke Pepsi Winter Summer Batman`  the result I would expect is [PC Coke Winter Summer] without Batman. And you still have only 50 integers per line which dose not correspond to the total possible count of 100 choises.

Comment: @Eritrean there are 50 pairs, and each student chooses one option from each pair. 0 = first option, 1 = second option.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your approach:

1. You are checking only the case `if (answers[i] == 0)` you need an else part to handle the case where that is not true, i.e where `answers[i] == 1`
2. your `answers` array is only half the size of your `choices` list and the `ith` index in the array holds information about the `i * 2` and `i * 2 + 1` choices. But at the moment you associate the `ith` index of `answers` with the `ith` index of your choices list.

Change the code in the inner loop of your `classSummary` method from:

```
public static void classSummary() {
    for (Student student : data) {
        int[] answers = student.getAnswers();
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if (answers[i] == 0) {
                choices.get(i).setCount(choices.get(i).getCount() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
public static void classSummary() {
    for (Student student : data) {
        int[] answers = student.getAnswers();
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if (answers[i] == 0) {
                choices.get(i * 2).setCount(choices.get(i * 2).getCount() + 1);
            } else {
                choices.get(i * 2 + 1).setCount(choices.get(i * 2 + 1).getCount() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand where my logic went wrong. I can't use your code, but I think I understand how to approach the problem now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could even shorten the code that @Eritrean suggested to:

```java
public static void classSummary() {
  for (Student student : data) {
    int[] answers = student.getAnswers();
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      int index = i * 2 + answers[i];
      choices.get(index).setCount(choices.get(index) + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

But you really should validate the inputs of that text file with the answers like:

```
while (inFile2.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = inFile2.nextLine();
  String[] x = line.split(",");
  String name = x[0];
  int[] answers = new int[x.length - 1];
  for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    answers[i - 1] = x[i].trim().equals("0") ? 0 : 1;
  }
  Student student = new Student(name, answers);
  data.add(student);
}
```

And you could either use a `Map<Integer>` instead of the `ArrayList<Choices>` (this means you would not need to implement the whole `Choices` class). In that case you either use a `HashMap` if the order of choices does not matter in the result, or a `LinkedHashMap` if the order of choices shall be kept in the order they appear in the input file.

Or you implement a method `increment` in your `Choices` class to improve the readability of your code:

```java
static class Choices {
  // ... existing parts go here
  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Instead of `choices.get(index).setCount(choices.get(index) + 1);` you would then only write `choices.get(index).increment();`